# Непонятная проверка типа удалителя в классе умного указателя

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, шаблоны-с++, конструктор

Не могу понять, зачем в [данном проекте](https://github.com/oliora/samples/blob/master/spimpl.h) используется конструкция `is_default_manageable`. Вроде бы в ней условное выражение в `std::is_same` тождественно выполняется как `true`.

Фрагменты кода из данного проекта:

```
template<class T>
void default_delete(T *p) SPIMPL_NOEXCEPT
{
    delete p;
}

template<class T>
struct default_deleter 
{
    using type = void (*)(T*);
};

template<class T>
using default_deleter_t = typename default_deleter<T>::type;

template<class T, class D>
struct is_default_manageable: public std::integral_constant
    <bool, std::is_same<D, default_deleter_t<T>>::value> 
{};
```

Сам класс, привожу к-р, принимающий делетер и второй - без него, использует по умолчанию

```
template<class T, class Deleter = details::default_deleter_t<T>>
class impl_ptr
{
    using pointer = T*;
    using element_type = T;
    using copier_type = typename std::decay<Copier>::type;
    using deleter_type = typename std::decay<Deleter>::type;
    using unique_ptr_type = std::unique_ptr<T, deleter_type>;
    using is_default_manageable = details::is_default_manageable<T, deleter_type>;

    template<class D>
    impl_ptr(pointer p, D&& d,
             typename std::enable_if<
                std::is_convertible<D, deleter_type>::value,
                dummy_t_
             >::type = dummy_t_())
    : ptr_(std::move(p), std::forward<D>(d)) {}

    template<class U>
    impl_ptr(U* u, typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U*,pointer>::value &&
        is_default_manageable::value, dummy_t_ >::type = dummy_t_()) 
    : impl_ptr(u, &details::default_delete<T>, &details::default_copy<T>) {}
};
```

Кое-что убрал, `copier` например, чтобы не захламлять схожим кодом вопрос.

Comment: Во-первых, с чего бы это вдруг `is_same` тождественно `true`? Я не вижу тут никакой тождественности. Во-вторых, во втором куске кода написана какая-то чушь. Почему не указаны параметры для `is_default_manageable`?

Comment: @AnT добавил строчку с псевдонимом, забыл скопировать из исходного проекта.

Comment: ОК. И? Где тут тождественность? Почему вы решили, что `deleter_type` всегда тождествен `default_deleter`?

Comment: @AnT Так идет же как аргумент по умолчанию. Не понимаю, как и зачем работает эта конструкция?

Comment: Ну так аргумент по умолчанию будет использоваться только *по умолчанию*. Никто не запрещает пользователю указать свой аргумент для `impl_ptr` - не по умолчанию.

Comment: @AnT А как вызвать второй к-р, без указания шаблонного параметра для удалителя, но с удалителем пользовательским? Он в принципе как аргумент не идет там, а только default_delete

Comment: Второй - никак. Если пользователь укажет свой `Deleter`, то второй конструктор сразу "выключится" именно благодаря тому, что `is_same` станет `false`, `is_default_manageable` станет `false`, и `enable_if` выключит конструктор. Останется только первый конструктор.

Comment: @AnT То, что он выключится, понимаю. Эта инструкция делает только это? Зачем вообще тогда отключать, если есть первый к-р, который два аргумента принимает и нормально все отработает?

Comment: Я не могу получить отличающееся поведение кода, если убрать этот default_manageable и если его оставить.

Comment: Второй конструктор надо отключать для того, чтобы *заставить* пользователя указывать именно *два* параметра в конструкторе. Если его не отключить, что у пользователя будет возможность случайно забыть указать значение deleter (т.к. второй конструктор требует только одного параметра).

Comment: @AnT спасибо, теперь понял.